# 403 Forbidden on react folder after build

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, build, http-status-code-403

I've read that is not a good practice to show 403 forbidden when trying to access a folder with no index.html and it should be added.

After I run build on react it creates a folder `images` and `static`, how to add a index.html file on those paths after build?

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/error-403-forbidden-explained-how-can-i-fix-this-http-error-code/